# Editablegrids HTML

Tags: mysql, ajax, editablegrid

am having a problem with editable grid from mySql DB.
It loads the data well but when I need to edit they pick only data from the first row only.
it doesn't load the other cell data on the update text boxes.

Any help will be appreciated.am useing this
http://www.editablegrid.net/en modules

Comment: Can you post some for you code ,So someone can help